# Unable to update original URL

Tags: sanity

I'm taking over an existing deployment

Made some changes which I attempted to deploy to the existing URL, was advised a URL needed to be set, the existing URL was marked as 'already in use'

For now I've uploaded the changes to a new URL, but this is less than ideal.

Is there a way to force the deploy to use the existing URL?

**things tried**
The define config under sanity.config.ts has the title matching the original URL as well as a matching projectID

Checked sanity.config.ts,
Settings for title, projectID, and dataset all matched values found on the manage projects screen

Unaware of any other configuration objects aside from sanity.cli.ts which i understand is for development settings

basepath seems to be related to configuring multiple workspaces not directing the root url